# How can I fix an error with adonis2 test?

Tags: r, error-handling, na, zero, vegan

I'm trying to carry out an adonis test (vegan package). My data has a column of a number of sites, and one with abundance data.

This is the code I tried to use:

`adonis2(abundance.data ~ site, method="bray")`

However, I keep getting this error message

> Error in vegdist(as.matrix(lhs), method = method, ...) :
> missing values are not allowed with argument 'na.rm = FALSE'

My dataset does have zero values but no NA values

Just wondering why this may be an how I can fix this issue

Comment: do you mean to use `adonis2(abundance~site, data=df, method="bray")`?  That is, your dataframe (in my example, called `df`) should be passed to the `data` parameter, and the formula can reference the column names in `df`.  However, this is only a guess; you usually get prompt and helpful feedback on SO if you provide a question with sufficient information (like a sample of your data, etc) that allows us to test solutions..

Comment: You should not argue with your computer: they will win. If the error message says that your lhs (`abundance.data`) has missing values, there are missing values. Probably some of your data was read as NA, possibly zeros, possibly an empty row or column at the end of the data set. What do you get if you issue command `sum(abndance.data)`? It will NA if you have one NA value in your data.